# How to best defer scripts to be excluded from PageSpeed Insights?

Tags: javascript, pagespeed, zopim

We use [Zopim](http://zopim.com/) on our website. Unfortunately, because of this we are significantly punished on [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/).

- Without Zopim: 86/100
- With Zopim: 66/100

Zopim seems to be aware of the [issue](https://chat.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/213947128-Google-PageSpeed-is-making-suggestions-for-Zopim-on-mobile), and promises to further optimize their widget, but we haven't seen much progress yet.

The code to add Zopim is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.$zopim||(function(d,s){var z=$zopim=function(c){z._.push(c)},$=z.s=
  d.createElement(s),e=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];z.set=function(o){z.set.
  _.push(o)};z._=[];z.set._=[];$.async=!0;$.setAttribute("charset","utf-8");
  $.src="https://v2.zopim.com/?2dAdkKRoqdi9hHHrfr302XabQaK8DN7f";z.t=+new Date;$.
  type="text/javascript";e.parentNode.insertBefore($,e)})(document,"script");
</script>
```

I have been playing around with different ways of deferring the execution of the script (defer and async), but have been unsuccessful in improving our PageSpeed Insights score (without removing Zopim altogether).

I came to this [article](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer-loading-javascript.html) but my naive attempt (replace "defer.js" with "https://v2.zopim.com/?2dAdkKRoqdi9hHHrfr302XabQaK8DN7f") did not have the desired effect and Zopim is still counted by PageSpeed.

My question:

- what is the best way to defer non-critical scripts to ensure that PageSpeed Insights do *not* count the script as part of its score?
- how to apply that to the Zopim script?

Comment: In the end we deferred Zopim by 4 seconds, which is sufficient for Google PageSpeed Insights to ignore it altogether in its score.

Comment: I'm dealing with this too was wondering if injecting from inside a `requestIdleCallback` would be enough...

Answer (score 4):

In this article is write the best solution: [here](https://marketingmakers.net/en/how-to-improve-zopim-zendesk-chat-load-time-or-any-other-external-javascript/)

"We changed the logic behind loading this script. The script loading starts when a user performs the first action. As an action we consider: scroll, mouse click, mouse move, touch on screen or keydown."

Work so nice!

```js
<script>
            document.addEventListener('scroll', zopimlaunch);
            document.addEventListener('mousedown', zopimlaunch);
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', zopimlaunch);
            document.addEventListener('touchstart', zopimlaunch);
            document.addEventListener('scroll', zopimlaunch);
            document.addEventListener('keydown', zopimlaunch);

            function zopimlaunch () {
                window.$zopim||(function(d,s){var z=$zopim=function(c){z._.push(c)},$=z.s=d.createElement(s),e=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];z.set=function(o){z.set._.push(o)};z._=[];z.set._=[];$.async=!0;$.setAttribute('charset','utf-8');
                $.src='//v2.zopim.com/?yourid';z.t=+new Date;$.type='text/javascript';e.parentNode.insertBefore($,e)})(document,'script');

                document.removeEventListener('scroll', zopimlaunch);
                document.removeEventListener('mousedown', zopimlaunch);
                document.removeEventListener('mousemove', zopimlaunch);
                document.removeEventListener('touchstart', zopimlaunch);
                document.removeEventListener('scroll', zopimlaunch);
                document.removeEventListener('keydown', zopimlaunch);
            }

</script>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me after hours of research. Thanks

Comment: Me too I'm looking for hours before to find this page. We have to say a big thank you to marketingmakers that shared this simple but super idea with us!

Answer (score 2):

Yes,zopim are not in my good books so I have also been messing around trying to fix their code. This is how I have deferred the zopim script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  function do_zopim() {
    jQuery(document).on("mousemove.zopim_defer scroll.zopim_defer", function(e) {
      window.$zopim||(function(d,s){var z=$zopim=function(c){z._.push(c)},$=z.s=
      d.createElement(s),e=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];z.set=function(o){z.set.
      _.push(o)};z._=[];z.set._=[];$.async=!0;$.setAttribute("charset","utf-8");
      $.src="https://v2.zopim.com/?anonymous";z.t=+new Date;$.
      type="text/javascript";e.parentNode.insertBefore($,e)})(document,"script");
      jQuery(document).off("mousemove.zopim_defer scroll.zopim_defer");
    });
  }
</script>

<body onload="do_zopim();">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding `$.setAttribute("defer",null);` at the end of the third line of javascript, so that it is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.$zopim||(function(d,s){var z=$zopim=function(c){z._.push(c)},$=z.s=
  d.createElement(s),e=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];z.set=function(o){z.set.
  _.push(o)};z._=[];z.set._=[];$.async=!0;$.setAttribute("charset","utf-8");$.setAttribute("defer",null);
  $.src="https://v2.zopim.com/?2dAdkKRoqdi9hHHrfr302XabQaK8DN7f";z.t=+new Date;$.
  type="text/javascript";e.parentNode.insertBefore($,e)})(document,"script");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've changed my site so that Zopim gets loaded after the page itself has loaded, as opposed to being an integral part of that initial page load.
Place this just before your `</body>`:

```
    <script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        window.$zopim || (function (d, s) {
            var z = $zopim = function (c) { z._.push(c) },
                $ = z.s = d.createElement(s), e = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; z.set = function (o) {
                    z.set._.push(o);
                }; z._ = []; z.set._ = []; $.async = !0; $.setAttribute('charset', 'utf-8');
            $.src = '//v2.zopim.com/?1ubUmoyGvu8nQlye7YBWC3pLL0lgJDUf'; z.t = +new Date; $.
                type = 'text/javascript'; e.parentNode.insertBefore($, e);
        })(document, 'script');
    })
</script>
```